# Adding multiple attachments to email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which generates a document, saves as a PDF and attaches to an email. In addition to this attachment, I'm trying to add a second attachment which is an existing PDF saved on google drive (terms). Why is the following code not attaching the second document?

```html
if (email_status == "YES" ) {
    //send a pdf copy to customer 
    var pdfEMAIL = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
    var terms = DriveApp.getFileById('file ID');  
    var message = "Hi " + usernamefordoctitle + "!, please kindly find your invoice attached.\nMany Thanks!\nMe";
    var emailAdd = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue()
    var emailTo = emailAdd; // add customer email here
    var subject = "Invoice for " + usernamefordoctitle + " from ME" + " - Invoice Number : " + newInvNumber;

    var attach = {fileName:"INVOICE " + newInvNumber + " " + usernamefordoctitle + '.pdf',content:pdfEMAIL, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach, terms.next()]});
    ss.toast("70%: emailed customer");
    Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
terms = DriveApp.getFileById('file ID');
```

followed by

```
terms.next()
```

This is incorrect, because `getFileById` gets you **one specific file** with the given Id. You were thinking of other methods like `getFilesByName` which return a **file iterator**. The name of the method is a clue to what it returns: getFile versus getFiles.

So, simply attaching

```
{attachments:[attach, terms]}
```

will work. You may also want to specify a MimeType like

```
terms.getAs(MimeType.PDF)
```

so that, e.g., you send a Google Doc as a PDF.